# JTextArea.append not displaying

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

I'm trying to write the contents of an array to a JTextArea. I've tried everything I can think of, and I can't understand what isn't working here. I've stripped the unnecessary stuff out of my code, here's the two relevant classfiles:

Main class:

```
package irclogtest;

public class BriBotMain {

public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {


    boolean startup = true;


    //frame test launch
    BriDisplayGUI data = new BriDisplayGUI(startup);
    data.irclog.append("BriBot Startup Successful!" + "\n");

    //example access through function when startup is false (only in main class for sample code to demonstrate issue)
    try { 
     BriDisplayGUI data2 = new BriDisplayGUI(false); //tells us which class we're accessing 

     String[] textForGUI = new String[2]; //tells us the array has 2 lines
     textForGUI[0] = "this is the first line"; //set the first line of the array to this text
     textForGUI[1] = "this is the second";

     data2.arrayToDisplay(textForGUI); //appends contents of array to text window
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
       System.out.println(e);
    }
}

}
```

GUI display class:

```
package irclogtest;


import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.swing.*;


public class BriDisplayGUI extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -7811223081379421773L;



String file_name = "C:/Bribot/logfile.txt";

//these lines create the objects we use
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
JPanel pane = new JPanel();
JButton pressme = new JButton("Click here");
JButton pressme2 = new JButton("Also here");
JTextArea irclog = new JTextArea( 20, 70);
JScrollPane scrollirc = new JScrollPane(irclog);

public BriDisplayGUI(boolean startup) { //startup function, opens and sets up the window

    if(startup == true){
        frame.setTitle("Bribot Test Frame"); frame.setBounds(100,100,840,420);      //sets title of window, sets position and size of window
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);       //tells program to end on window close
        frame.add(pane);        //adds the main display pane to the window   
        //panel customization goes here
        pressme.addActionListener(this);
        pane.add(pressme);
        pressme2.addActionListener(this);
        pane.add(pressme2);
        pressme.requestFocusInWindow();
        irclog.setEditable(false);
        scrollirc.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy( JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        pane.add(scrollirc);
        irclog.setLineWrap(true);
        irclog.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        //pane.add(inputthing);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Display Class Called");
    }

}




public void arrayToDisplay(String[] text) throws IOException {

   int i;
   for ( i=0; i < text.length; i++) {
       irclog.append( text[i] + "\n");
       System.out.println( i + ": " + text[i]);
   }
}
public void singleToDisplay(String text) throws IOException {

    irclog.append(text + "\n");
    System.out.println(text);
}


//basic event handler
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
    Object source = event.getSource();
    if (source == pressme) {


    } else if(source == pressme2) {

    }
}

}
```

The first append works fine, but the second doesn't, and I can't figure out why (although the for loop does, as the contents of the array get written to console). I've searched quite a bit and nothing I've tried works. Can anyone point out the inevitable obvious oversight here? I'm the definition of a novice, so any advice is appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The default constructor doesn't do anything, meaning it doesn't construct any kind of UI or display, what would be, an empty frame.

You seem to be thinking the text will appear in `data` when you are appending it to `data1`

Try calling `this(false)` within the default constructor

A better solution would be to construct the core UI from the default constructor and from the "startup" constructor call `this()` and then modify the UI in what ever way this constructor needs

Comment: I've updated my code above - I tried both solutions you presented, but they only half worked; the text did display, but it opens a new window instead of appending to the same. As far as I can tell, the issue isn't related to calling `data` or `data1`. The array does get passed to the display class just fine(the `System.out.println` command works fine), but it doesn't appear in the textarea (unless I set startup to true, which makes it open a new window with the text).

Comment: Don't create a second BriDisplayGUI then, simple call "data" and discard "data1" altogether

Comment: Data and data1 are two completely separate instances of the same object, they have no relationship to each other, so call data1.arrayToDiaplay will have no effect on data...

Comment: Wow, that seems so obvious now. Thanks for the help, I definitely wouldn't have made that connection alone.

Answer (score -1):

It seems like you write a new program. Why do you use Swing? Did you take a look at JavaFX?

I am not sure if that is going to fix your problem but you could try a foreach

```
for(String s : text){
    irclog.append(s+"\n");
}
```